# Creating A MySQL event procedure which inserts a new record into database every day for each employee id in another table

Tags: mysql

Good Day

I have two tables named as **Users** and **mileagesnew**

The **users** table has an id which is unique (Primary Key) and the `users.id` column acts as a foreign key in the **mileagesnew** table.

The Users Table
[image: Users Table]

The mileagesnew Table
[image: Mileage Table]

I want to create a MySQL event to insert a new mileage record for each and every user in the **Users** table inside the **mileagesnew** table

So, the MySQL trigger i have right now is,

```
CREATE EVENT Daily_Mileage
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS (TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
DO
INSERT INTO `mileagesnew`(`user_id`, `date`, `mileage`, `fuel_mileage`, `fuel`, `fuel_cost`, `km`, 
`kmpl`, `remarks`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
('Need To Get The ID of every employee in users table here without 
repeating',CURRENT_DATE,'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

I am not sure how i can get the id value of each records present in the users table without having any duplicates. Is this possible or if i am doing this via mysql should i write the query individually for all users

So far the event set will run only for one user id but not for other which is set as follows,

[image: Event Set]
[image: Event Query]

Comment: This is event procedure, not trigger. Trigger is fired only by according data change event.

Comment: What is `mileagesnew` in your SQL code? you have not mentioned such table eslewhere..

Comment: @Akina oops sorry my bad the table name is mileagesnew not Mileage

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text

Comment: @Strawberry those pictures are for the references of how the event is set not to edit them and provide as an answer. I have added the code block seperatly for the community to provide me a clarification in case if something is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE EVENT Daily_Mileage
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS (TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
DO
INSERT INTO Mileages (user_id, `date`, mileage, fuel_mileage, fuel, fuel_cost, km, kmpl, remarks) 
SELECT id, CURRENT_DATE, 0, '0', '0', '0', 0, 0, ''
FROM Users;
```

PS. `created_at` and `updated_at` columns are already `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, so they're removed. Single quotes wrapped zeros for numeric columns are removed.

PPS. `TIMESTAMP` function usage in `STARTS` is excess, `STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 1' DAY_HOUR` is enough.

---

> the table name is mileagesnew not Mileage – Developer

Adjust it in the query by yourself.

Comment: How can the query know on which table to fetch the id by setting the query as SELECT id etc.. will get the id from the users table which is another table in the database

Comment: @Developer This is explicitly set by `FROM Users`. If you need to insert new rows for some users only then add according WHERE.